# Polymer icon transition

Tags: javascript, css, transition, polymer

I would like to animate an icon when I transition from one page to another.

On one page,  I have the hamburger menu button in the top bar. Then I click on an element that becomes full screen. The hamburger menu was replaced by a left arrow. Is it possible to have a nice animation between those 2 icons? (paper design style like)

Thanks 
nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the polymerlabs icon-transition element could work

https://github.com/PolymerLabs/icon-transition